# How to prevent "conflicting" firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a set of objects that has a time-based derived property.

I have a Firebase cloud function that is listening for creates and writes to calculate the property and it is working well.

I have also added a function that is triggered via HTTP, like a cron, to recalculate the property early in the morning on Sunday (this property will change weekly).

This is working fine, but whenever the cron function updates a property, the first function catches the write and does the whole calculation over again.

Is there a simple way to prevent this? I've explored setting an environment variable for the first function to detect if the cron is running, but it doesn't seem that environment variables can be set at runtime.

Comment: Why do you need the cron job? The first function does the calculation on updates.

Comment: The cron job is needed because one of the factors that goes into the derived property is based on a weekly cycle. So the derived property can change based on the user's updates or by the calendar turning over another week.

Comment: So maybe the cron job could just perform a write/update to a node (called "update" for example)  which would trigger the first function. :-)

Comment: I thought about this approach, but it would involve a duplicate write. I'm not sure how expensive a write operation is, but it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to prevent this by checking the previous value. I'll try to provide an example

```
exports.yourFunction = functions.database.ref('/somepath/{someKey}').onWrite(event => {
  if (event.data.previous.val().time != event.data.val().time) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    // perform calculation
  }
 });
```

In summary if the previous value is not the same as the current value then the variable `time` was just changed by your other function. You'll need to change `.time` to your variable name.

Note: This does not prevent the function from firing, it only prevents it from preforming the calculation again. If you don't want the function to fire at all you'll have to devise a different way of calculating the value. Such as only calculating it `onCreate` then use the Cron at a set time interval to update the values. Listening to `onWrite` will cause the function to fire everytime data is written to Firebase.

You can read more about [Firebase Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Comment: I don't think what you are proposing would work, if I understand you correctly.

The "cron" is the trigger for the onWrite event, so the previous value and the event value will be different by necessity. Right?

Comment: The "cron" function will write to the database. Which triggers the cloud function. event.data.previous.val().time = the value before the "cron" function. event.data.val().time is the value after the trigger (which is also after the "cron" function. If those two values are not the same then we know the trigger was set off by the "cron" function so we ignore it. For any other write where the time value has not been changed the function will perform as expected.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing. Clever.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** My approach is a bit heavy handed, and it would probably require a refactoring of your code, so definitely not a solution for you. But I thought it might still interest either you or future readers.

---

I worked around this by using "commands" (what should be done) and "events" (what has happened). Each has it's own collection, to which my two functions (a `CommandsHandler` and an `EventsHandler`) are subscribed.

Each handler handles the commands and events, and may or may not generate their own events and commands depending on what they did, allowing me to completely bypass the kind of issues you described.

In your case, it would behave like the following:

#### Updates

Command `Update item 'Item' with 'blablabla'` -> Event `Item 'Item' updated` -> Command `Calculate property 'Property' for item 'Item'` -> Event `Property 'Property' updated in item 'Item'`

#### Cron

Cron function trigger -> Command `Calculate property 'Property' for item 'Item'` -> Event `Property 'Property' updated in item 'Item'`